# show page when loaded

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, hide, show

I've tried multiple solutions, and nothing works for me.
I tried this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').show();
});
</script>
```

And with :

```
$(window).load(function() {.
```

The page loads as if it was not there.

Does someone have a code that works for real?

Patrick

Comment: Can you explain: "The page loads as if it was not there."? And what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't understand. The <body> of your page will be visible by default. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why is `body` hidden in the first place? If you want to hide content until everything loads, you should use a loading screen.

Comment: I simply want to see the page only when it is fully loaded.

Comment: OK. So your page has parts which are loaded dynamically, and you want to hide the whole page until all of these parts are loaded?

Answer (score 0):

can add a script tag in head that will create a style tag to hide body with css. Using script to create style tag means hiding body with default css won't affect user if js disabled

```
<script>
/* place in head tag so it fires before body is present*/
document.write('<style>body{display:none}</style>')

</script>
```

Then use jQuery to show within ready handler.

If problem is related to needing images loaded, there are many many posts on here to create image preloading script you could use to show body once all images loaded

Answer (score 0):

i think u mean like that

```
   <script>  document.write('<style>body{display:none}</style>') </script>  // in head tag
       <script type="text/javascript">

      $(window).load(function() {
   $('body').show();
  });
     </script>
```

Comment: problem is if the code is in head...body doesn't exist when code fires

Comment: I bet that you don't want to insert `body` tag "in head tag" ;)

Comment: Yes, why body tag inside head tag?!?  See the post below (only problem remaining is with firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you set `display:none` in the body in the first place:

```
<body style="display:none;">
```

and then in the `script` tag you'll show it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="display:none;">
        <p>Text</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){$('body').show();});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is ALMOST working with $(window).load : <body style="display:none;">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){$('body').show();});
</script>            But now when the body show, one widget is appearing after body is loaded. I want ALL to appear in the same time.  (oh! it works with IE though!)

Comment: What do you mean by "widget"? Is this some javascript/ajax invoked popup or `div`?

Comment: Somewhere I have : <script> freedjit  </script> <p>text</p>.   When it loads, I see first the text, then freedjit goes above the text.  I want all to loads at the same time.

Comment: Can you invoke `show()` on this widget before `$('body').show();`?

Comment: Well I cannot use this solution. With that, in firefox, my shoutbox displays the last page of all shouts. Too bad, it's ok in IE.

Comment: Xeon, I don't think it's possible to invoke show on the widget before.

Comment: I think that the widget listens if it can be visible, etc. Try maybe instead `show()` - `fadeIn('slow')`, etc. or `$('body').delay(5000).show();` if that satisfies you.

Comment: It doesn't work, because I think it's the way firefox shows the body, even if already fully loaded.